# Nuxt not automatically importing components from nested directory

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

In my nuxt app, components in nested directories are not automatically importing as expected. For some of my components i have something like the following:

`vue 2.6.12`, `nuxt 2.15.0`

`components\` Directory structure

```
TopArea\
--SomeComponent.vue
```

```
<template>
  <header class="header">
    <div>Hello</div>
    <SomeComponent />
  </header>
</template>
```

No other component in the application has the name `SomeComponent`. In the example above i get the error: `Unknown custom element: <SomeComponent> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.`. I can get around the issue by specifying the directory name before the component filename (`TopAreaSomeComponent`), use the prefix option in nuxt.config, or by manually importing the component. This is confusing because the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/components) state:

> Nested Directories
> If you have components in nested directories such as:
> `components/baseButton.vue`
> The component name will be based on its own filename. Therefore, the component will be:
> `<button />`

It goes on to say "We recommend you use the directory name in the filename for clarity". But that seems like a rule than a recommendation. If i don't use the directory name as part of the filename, dynamic imports are not working for components in nested directories.

Is this an error in the docs or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: Just an fyi for future visitors, this is no longer a problem. The docs have been updated to reflect how it actually works in the current version

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Since Nuxt 2.15.0, `components` changed in the way they work as stated in this [github issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/8851#issuecomment-781351562).

Depending of you structure and how you want to handle your organization, you may edit your configuration accordingly to the migration guide available here: https://github.com/nuxt/components#v1-to-v2

Or you could also simply set the `pathPrefix` option to have all your components available without any prefix at all.

`nuxt.config.js/ts`

```js
components: [
  {
    path: '~/components', // will get any components nested in let's say /components/test too
    pathPrefix: false,
  },
]
```

PS: this solution also works with Nuxt3.

This documentation actually do need an update, indeed: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/components#components-discovery

---

This is how it works: for a given page

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <yolo-swag /> <!-- no need for <nested-yolo-swag /> here -->
  </div>
</template>
```

And with the following file tree

[image]

---

#### Update for Nuxt3

[Looks like](http://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/components/#dynamic-components) this is the new official syntax

```js
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  components: {
    global: true,
    dirs: ['~/components']
  },
})
```

Comment: Documentation issue being worked on in https://github.com/nuxt/nuxtjs.org/pull/1279

Answer (score 8):

This may answered already. But to illustrate the solution to comers here here's the way according to docs:

```html
<TopAreaSomeComponent />
```

if your components is nested deeply:

`components / TopArea / SomeComponent.vue`

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/components/#nested-directories