# vue can't querySelector for child component DOM element

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I cannot search for child component DOM element, my settings are as follows:

pages/Login.vue

```html
<template>
 <section class="login">
    <div v-show="step === 4" class="login__container">
      <Test />
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      step: 1
    }
  },
  async mounted () {
      this.step = 4 
      await this.$nextTick()
      document.querySelector('.test') // NULL
  },
}
</script>
```

components/Test.vue

```html
<template>
  <div class="test">
    foo
  </div>
</template>
```

setTimeout of course is not solution. I also try the same on other page, but without success. What am I doing wrong? I guess the problem must be somewhere in the template or project configuration

@edit

i tried to do the same effect on jsfiddle vue template and fresh nuxt project but no problem there

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here, but be careful with this kind of logic. This is usually not the recommended way to go. Also yeah, `setTimeout` is never really a great solution!

Comment: usually I use refs, but I rewrote that quickly, my mistake

Answer (score 2):

This kind of code should work properly

`parent.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <test ref="parentTest" @hook:mounted="selectChildElement"></test>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    selectChildElement() {
      console.log(this.$refs.parentTest.$refs.test)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

`Test.vue` component

```html
<template>
  <div ref="test">foo</div>
</template>
```

This is because of the way the parent and children components are mounted, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44319825/8816585

---

As Brahim said, it is also better to use `$refs` in an SPA context, more info available [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements).

The `@hook:mounted` trick was taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67535239/8816585) and initially found in this [dev.to post](https://dev.to/rolanddoda/8-secrets-vue-developers-must-know-5la#how-to-know-if-a-child-component-is-mounted-).

Comment: Your approach is correct and I have used it so far, but my logic does not fit that approach a bit. And I have finally found the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to access child component is emitting event when its ready and created in `DOM`,

In the child element:

```html
    <template>
      <div ref="test">foo</div>
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {
      mounted() {
        this.$emit('childMounted', this.$refs.test)
      }
    }
    ...
```

In your parent:

```html
    <template>
     <section class="login">
        <div v-show="step === 4" class="login__container">
          <Test @childMounted="childMounted"/>
        </div>
      </section>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      data () {
        return {
          step: 1
        }
      },
      methods: {
       childMounted(childRef) {
         // Try here 
         // childRef: your child component reference
       }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: This is also a great way of doing things!

Comment: @JanuszO did you try this approach ?

Comment: I already know where the problem is, I will describe it soon

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `ref` instead of `querySelector` to manipulate the component DOM :

```html
<template>
 <section class="login">
    <div v-show="step === 4" class="login__container">
      <Test ref="test"/>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      step: 1
    }
  },
  mounted () {
      this.step = 4 
   
      let test=this.$refs.test
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I thought, the problem is with nuxt, namely auto-importing components.
I am using automatic component import in the nuxt configuration.

nuxt.config.js

```js
  components: [
    {
      path: '~/components',
      pathPrefix: false,
    },
  ],
```

This approach apparently breaks something, and only after manually importing the component did it work properly

```
import Test from '@/components/Test.vue'

export default {
  name: 'LoginPage',
  components: {
    Test
  },
```

So the nuxt configuration caused the problem. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Can you show us the directory of your project? Also does it have a `name`?

Comment: it's standard nuxt structure

Comment: it's your approach :-P https://stackoverflow.com/a/66336654/6345056

Comment: generally auto importing components works fine, for nested structures too, but I have no idea why this hook doesn't fire what it should

Comment: Do you have a `name` on them?

Comment: i don't understand the question. This files are in "projectdir/nuxt.config.js" and "projectdir/components/SomeName.vue"

Comment: no errors, just not find DOM element from parent component like in example above

Comment: This is very strange because I can't bring it up on a new project, and I haven't done anything else to fix it

Comment: Do you have `name: 'Test',` in your `Test.vue` component? Do you maybe have a `<lazy-test></lazy-test>`? Also, be sure to have both `ref` on both components. Otherwise, I guess we will need a [repro].

Comment: What if you delete `node_modules` and install them again?

Comment: I did it, but no change