# How to Model Bind Tinymce in NuxtJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have installed Tinymce on my nuxt js project using `npm i tinymce` and it installed `v6` i then did the following in the nuxt.config.js file

```
plugins: [
      '~/plugins/axios',
      {
        src: "~/plugins/tinymce.js",
        mode: "client",
        ssr: false
      }
    ]
```

I created a tinymce.js file inside the plugins folder and i have all this inside it

```
import tinymce from "tinymce"
import "tinymce/themes/silver"
import "tinymce/plugins/table"
import "tinymce/plugins/link"
import "tinymce/plugins/image"
import "tinymce/plugins/lists"
import "tinymce/plugins/code"
import "tinymce/plugins/fullscreen"
import "tinymce/icons/default"
import 'tinymce/models/dom'
import "tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/skin.min.css"
import "tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/content.min.css"
import "tinymce/skins/content/default/content.css"
import "tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/skin.min.css"
import "tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/content.min.css"
import "tinymce/skins/content/default/content.css"
import "tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/skin.min.css"
import "tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/content.min.css"
import "tinymce/skins/content/default/content.css"
import "tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/skin.min.css"
import "tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/content.min.css"

export default tinymce
```

i then did this inside my .vue file

```html
<textarea
  v-model="body"
  id="main"
  type="text"
  class="border-0 px-3 py-3 placeholder-blueGray-300 text-blueGray-600 bg-white rounded text-sm shadow focus:outline-none focus:ring w-full ease-linear transition-all duration-150"
  rows="4"
>
</textarea>
```

Script

```
 data:() =>({
    errors: [],
    title: '',
    body: '',
    excerpt: ''
  }),
mounted(){
    tinymce.init({
      selector: 'textarea#main',
      height: 500,
      skin: false,
      content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }',
      plugins: 'image code',
      images_file_types: 'jpg,png,jpeg'
    })
  }
```

But the data does not send to the database so i keep getting validation error on the body.

1. How can i solve this
2. Anytime i navigate away from the page in which tinymce is to another page on the browser i need to refresh the browser to see the tinymce editor when i go back to the page where it is. (How can i solve this)?

Comment: Don't use `ssr: false` and don't use a query selector, rather a Vue ref (check vue 2 documentation). As about the plugin itself, I've shared a link on how to implement this with Vue in your latest question.

Comment: @kissu i followed the instructions in the github link and it worked finally even with v-model. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71594866/8816585) is solving the exact same issue, even with the `v-model` apparently.

Query selectors should not be used but rather [`refs`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68845811/8816585) are recommended!