# NUXT project cannot build

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am writing an admin panel on the nuxt + nest stack.
I'm using this template: https://github.com/stephsalou/nuxt-nest-template

In dev mode, the project starts normally, but I just want to build and errors appear right away. This file is compiled by nuxt itself

```js
  11 | export const LoadingPanel = () => import('../../client/components/LoadingPanel.vue' /* webpackChunkName: "components/loading-panel" */).then(c => wrapFunctional(c.default || c))
  12 | export const Modal = () => import('../../client/components/Modal.vue' /* webpackChunkName: "components/modal" */).then(c => wrapFunctional(c.default || c))
> 13 | export const  = () => import('../../client/components/index.ts' /* webpackChunkName: "components/" */).then(c => wrapFunctional(c.default || c))
     |               ^
  14 | export const Breadcrumb = () => import('../../client/components/Breadcrumb/Breadcrumb.vue' /* webpackChunkName: "components/breadcrumb" */).then(c => wrapFunctional(c.default || c))
  15 | export const BreadcrumbItem = () => import('../../client/components/Breadcrumb/BreadcrumbItem.vue' /* webpackChunkName: "components/breadcrumb-item" */).then(c => wrapFunctional(c.default || c))
  16 | export const BreadcrumbRouteBreadcrumb = () => import('../../client/components/Breadcrumb/RouteBreadcrumb.vue' /* webpackChunkName: "components/breadcrumb-route-breadcrumb" */).then(c => wrapFunctional(c.default || c))
```

I found the reason for this error. In the components folder there is index.ts which collects all the components and from this file I already take the components that I need. ** Nuxt enters the component folder and considers all files as components, and collects them all in one form. ** These components are taken from the admin template, I cannot remove index.ts, because it is used a lot and it will break everything. There was a similar error on dev mode, but changing index.js to index.ts helped.

How can this problem be solved??

Nuxt Config

```js
const config: NuxtConfig = {
  // Disabled nuxt telemetry
  telemetry: false,
  /*
   ** Nuxt rendering mode
   ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-mode
   */
  mode: 'universal',
  // base nuxt src dir
  srcDir: './client',
  /*
   ** Nuxt target
   ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-target
   */
  target: 'server',
  /*
   ** Headers of the page
   ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-head
   */
  head: {
    title: 'Admin Products SeaRates',
    meta: [
      {charset: 'utf-8'},
      {name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1'},
      {
        hid: 'description',
        name: 'description',
        content: process.env.npm_package_description || '',
      },
    ],
    link: [
      {rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico'},
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,600,700,800'},
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/css/all.min.css'}
    ]
  },
  router: {
    linkExactActiveClass: 'active'
  },
  /*
   ** Global CSS
   */
  css: [
    '@/assets/scss/index.scss',
    '@/assets/css/demo.css',
    '@/assets/css/nucleo-icons.css'
  ],
  /*
   ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
   ** https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins
   */
  plugins: [
    `@/plugins/dashboard-plugin.js`
  ],
  /*
   ** Auto import components
   ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-components
   */
  components: true,
  /*
   ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
   */
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxt/typescript-build',
  ],
  netlify: {
    headers: {
      '/*': [
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *',
        `X-Build: ${pkg.version}`
      ],
      '/favicon.ico': [
        'Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400'
      ]
    }
  },
  /*
   ** Nuxt.js modules
   */
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    '@nuxt/content',
    'cookie-universal-nuxt'
  ],
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    axios: {
      baseURL: `${url}/api`
    }
  },
  /*
   ** Axios module configuration
   ** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
   */
  axios: {},
  /*
   ** Content module configuration
   ** See https://content.nuxtjs.org/configuration
   */
  content: {},

  loading: { color: '#389466' },

  /*
   ** Build configuration
   ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/
   */
  build: {

  },
  alias: {
    "@/*": resolve(__dirname, './client'),
  }
}

export default config
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you import all the components if you already have the auto-importing by Nuxt?
Either use one or the other. Or you could exclude a specific one with something like this in your `nuxt.config.js` file

```js
components: [
  {
    path: '~/components/',
    pathPrefix: false,
    pattern: `**/*.{vue,js,ts}`,
    ignore: ["~/components/index.ts"]
  }
]
```

Not sure if you do actually use TS or not, but the default fetches `.vue` and `.js` files.

`pathPrefix` is useful if you want to grab all the components, even the nested ones, as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66336654/8816585).

Use `ignore` to just not import the `index` one.

At the end, giving a read to this tutorial may be useful to see if you can let `components: true` or make some modifications to the default behavior as explained above: https://nuxtjs.org/tutorials/improve-your-developer-experience-with-nuxt-components/