# How to add miultiple components in a single template in Nuxt Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

### summery

I've tried to create some sample Vue Nuxt SPA.
Within a component, I added other two components.
It results that nothing displayed on the browser.

I want to know how to fix it and display input function correctly.

### what I've tried

here is directory structure.

```
project
  ├ pages
  │  └ index.vue
  ├ components
  │  ├ home
  │  │  └ index.vue
  │  ├ input
  │  │  └ index.vue
  │  └ list
  │     └ index.vue
  .
  .
```

In `components/home/index.vue` I added two components: Input and List.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <Input/>
    <List/>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator';
import Input from '~/components/input/index.vue';
import List from '~/components/list/index.vue';

@Component({
  layout: 'default',
  components: {
    Input,
    List,
  },
})
export default class Home extends Vue {}
</script>
```

As the result, Nothing is displayed on the browser.
[image]

### show some codes

Here is the Github repository, please check.
https://github.com/jpskgc/vue-nuxt-spa-sample/tree/multiple-components

Comment: Hi, did my answer helped somehow? Please upvote/accept if it did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it is caused by lack of @component annnotation.

input/index.vue

```html
<template>
  <v-text-field label="Main input" :rules="rules" hide-details="auto" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator';

@Component # <- add it.
export default class Input extends Vue {}
</script>
```

list/index.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>List</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator';

@Component # <- add it
export default class List extends Vue {}
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, you indeed need this one if you're using TS.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `nuxt.config.js`, setup it as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66336654/8816585).

```js
export default {
  components: [
    {
      path: '~/components', // will get any components nested in let's say /components/test too
      pathPrefix: false,
    },
  ]
}
```

That way, you'll get auto-importing components. Then, you'll be able to rename your components directly to `Home.vue`, `Input.vue` and `List.vue` and use them directly into your template.

You can check this repo for additional details on the auto-importing components feature: https://github.com/nuxt/components

And read this article that explain a bit better what the auto-importing is all about: https://nuxtjs.org/tutorials/improve-your-developer-experience-with-nuxt-components

If you need some guidelines as how to name + organize your components, you may refer to this one: https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/how-to-structure-a-large-scale-vue-js-application/

Comment: I added it in `nuxt.config.js` but still it is not displayed...

Comment: @jpskgc we will probably need a [repro] here.