# Nuxt 3 ignore filepath for naming components?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm migrating over to [NuxtJS 3](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/), but my project has several levels of `component` folders:

```
/components 
     /foo
          file.vue
          file2.vue
               /fooTwo
                    anotherfile.vue
     /bar
          file1.vue
          file10.vue
 etc...
```

Because of [Nuxt's naming convention](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/components#component-names), if I try to import the `anotherfile` component I'd have to rename every place it's used inside my codebase to this: `<FooFooTwoanotherfile/>`

Because their [documentation states](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/components#component-names):

> the component's name will be based on its own path directory and filename

I really don't want to go through and rename every place that the component is being used. And I also would prefer to not flatten my directory structure either. So, is there some config option in Nuxt 3 that overrides this and lets me just globally call the components by their original name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66336654/8816585) is still relevant for Nuxt3

`nuxt.config.ts`

```js
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  components: [
    {
      path: '~/components', // will get any components nested in let's say /components/nested
      pathPrefix: false,
    },
  ]
})
```

And will allow you to auto-import components without the need to specify a nested path for the components.

`/pages/index.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <yolo-swag /> <!-- no need for <nested-yolo-swag /> here -->
  </div>
</template>
```

With the following file structure

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As @kissu suggested this is the answer:

`nuxt.config.ts`

```js
components: [
  {
    path: '~/components', // will get any components nested in let's say /components/test too
    pathPrefix: false, //<------------------- here
  },
]
```