# Components auto imports in Nuxt 3 with modules

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I want to use modules (so not the default structure directories) with Nuxt, something like that:

[image]

The problem is that I don't know how to configure Nuxt or my module to auto import the components in nested folders like the `Card` folders. For example the `PlanChoiceCard.vue` component is auto imported but not `NestedComponent.vue`

This is my `nuxt.config.js`:

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from "nuxt";

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: true,
  ignore: ["node_modules/**/*"],
  plugins: ["~/plugins/vue-i18n.client.ts"],
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      myapp: {
        version: "1.7.8.2",
      },
    },
  },
  modules: ["./modules/Plans"],
  build: {
    postcss: {
      postcssOptions: {
        plugins: {
          tailwindcss: {},
          autoprefixer: {},
        },
      },
    },
  },
  css: ["~/assets/css/tailwind.css"],
});
```

and the configuration of the `Plans` module:

```
import path from "path";
import { defineNuxtModule } from "@nuxt/kit";

export default defineNuxtModule({
  // Default configuration options for your module
  defaults: {},
  hooks: {
    // ROUTES
    "pages:extend"(pages) {
      pages.push({
        name: "user",
        path: "/",
        file: path.resolve(__dirname, "./views/PlanChoices.vue"),
      });
    },

    // COMPONENTS
    "components:dirs"(dirs) {
      // Add ./components dir to the list
      dirs.push({
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./components"),
      });
    },

    // COMPOSABLES
    // "autoImports:dirs"(dirs) {
    //  dirs.push(path.resolve(__dirname, "./composables"));
    // },
  },
  async setup(moduleOptions, nuxt) {
    // -- Add your module logic here --
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was to make the same as in `nuxt.config.ts`:

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/66336654/10805872

So:

```
    // COMPONENTS
    "components:dirs"(dirs) {
      // Add ./components dir to the list
      dirs.push({
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./components"),
      });
    },
```

become:

```
    // COMPONENTS
    "components:dirs"(dirs) {
      // Add ./components dir to the list
      dirs.push({
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./components"), pathPrefix: false
      });
    },
```

With the prefix you have to use it, for example a component in `modules/user/localeSwitcher.vue`, as `<user-locale-switcher />`

Without prefix so `pathPrefix: false`, you can use directly `<locale-switcher />`