# I can't use dynamic components in Nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I try to get this to work

```html
<component v-if="!pending" :is="dynComponent" />
```

In Nuxt 2 it was no problem, but in Nuxt 3 (Vue 3 ?) it doesn't seem so easy.

The variable `dynComponent` is filled with the name of the component in the course of the process (myComponent).

As in Nuxt 2, I import the corresponding component with `import myComponent from "@/layouts/myComponent.vue"`. The error is probably there.

I read in the docs that the use of `resolveComponent` helper is required. I've also tried as described...but without success. ([Dynamic components](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/components/#dynamic-components))

I don't get any error messages either. Nothing happens.
Can someone explain me how to use dynamic components in Nuxt 3?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is how you should write your dynamic component.

```html
<script setup>
const yolo = resolveComponent('Yolo')
const bob = resolveComponent('Bob')
const boolean = ref(true)
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <div>{{ boolean }}</div>
    <component :is="boolean ? yolo : bob" />
    <button @click="boolean = !boolean">toggle</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

With this kind of structure

[image]

Comment: Yeah ... this works for me. Thank you! But do the components always have to be on the first level in the components folder? Can't use subfolders?

Comment: @Tobi360 if you have a structure like `/components/nested/Bob.vue`, then the name would be `nested/Bob`. Otherwise, you can always a solution like this to flatten them all: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66336654/8816585

Comment: Any idea how to do this with replacing a string? See my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75555611/4638682

Comment: @Tobi360 thanks, you section solution didn't work, however the link did. Thanks!

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work with variable. how to get resolveComponent to work like const bob = resolveComponent(name) ?

Comment: @namvo I'm not sure how that works with a dynamic import but it will probably not be good for performance anyway, having a static array of possible components is the best still IMO. For dynamic components, there is probably a way but I'm not sure how to do it with Vite!

Comment: thanks, but do you know how this could also be resolved in storybook 7 for nuxt? As in the current way component does not load properly also

Comment: @Gesha I don't have any experience with Storybook 7 but you could probably look into the Github issues or ask a question down there regarding this specific use case by linking my answer.

Comment: It looks good, but how does it work with more than 2 components ? For exemple, I use it in a modal and I use it to load the good component in some parts ot my nuxt App. So I've lot of possibilities

Comment: It's not working with nested for me.
I am using 
`const HeaderBottomItem = resolveComponent('Header/HeaderBottomItem');`
and `:is=HeaderBottomItem` (for exmpl) is rendering like tag and warning in console

Comment: @Sinneren gonna probably need more details for that one. Feel free to open a new question with a [repro].

Answer (score 0):

As I saw some other people to continue to ask and I struggled with this as well, here's my proposed solution after getting it to work. You can adapt it to whatever is needed, but I tried to cover all bases with this example.

```html
<script setup>
import { MyComponentA, MyComponentB } from '#components'

// type can be 'a' or 'b'
const props = defineProps(['type', 'data'])

const typeComponent = computed(() => {
  const map = {
    a: MyComponentA,
    b: MyComponentB,
  }

  return map[props.type]
})
</script>

<template>
  <component :is="typeComponent" :data="data" />
</template>
```

With this, you can still benefit from all the Nuxt Magic regarding component naming and so on. So if your component lies in `components/my/component/A.vue` it will work as expected.