# Vue 3 resolveComponent returns [object Object]

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, shortcode

I'm trying to replace a (WordPress) shortcode string that comes from a REST API.
Now I want to replace '[faq]' with a Vue 3 component called 'FAqItem'.
For this, I use the function resolveComponent().

REST API data:

```
{
  "flow": "col",
  "subtitle": "Programma",
  "title": "Wat ga je doen?",
  "text": "Test\r\n\r\n[faq]"
}
```

And this is my code:

```
const html = ref(props.data.text)
const FaqItem = resolveComponent('FaqItem')
if (html.value.includes('[faq]')) {
    html.value = html.value.replace('[faq]', FaqItem);
}
```

Then in my template I use:

```
<div class="block prose xl:mt-12" v-html="html"></div>
```

Now this seems to work, but the replace function is returning `[object Object]`.
How can I make this show my component itself?
It's important that only the [faq] is replaced.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked that `props.data.text` is not an object?

Comment: No, that's HTML formatted text.

Comment: Can you add it to the question?

Comment: since your `FaqItem` component is found, `resolveComponent` will return it as an object

Reference: https://vuejs.org/api/render-function.html#resolvecomponent

What do you want?

Comment: I want it to output the component. Not just [object Object].

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the problem comes from this line:

```
html.value = html.value.replace('[faq]', FaqItem);
```

The `FaqItem` variable contains an object, which is then inserted into a string. So JS calls `.toString()` on it, which returns `[object Object]`.

Using template syntax (i.e. `<FaqItem />`) won't work either, since `v-html` only processes plain HTML.

Not sure if it is just me, but I think Vue does not really want you to do things like that. So if there is a way to avoid it, that's your best option.

However, there are options to compile and insert a template (meaning you might find a better one if you search the web). One is to use `h()` with an ad-hoc component:

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
  import { h } from 'vue';

  const myTemplateRenderer = () => {
    const myTemplate = 'asdf <FaqItem /> asdf'
    return h({template: myTemplate, components: {FaqItem} });
  };

</script>
<template>

  <myTemplateRenderer />

</template>
```

There are also plugins like [vue3-runtime-template](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-runtime-template) that you could use.

Note that this means that your [production build needs to include the template compiler](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/tooling.html#project-scaffolding), which will increase your build size by around 80kB/30kB gzipped.

Comment: this is so heavy it causes the production build to include the template compiler

Comment: @TachibanaShin Interesting! Also makes sense. Is there a way around that? If OP wants to compile templates at runtime, that's probably the price to pay. Do you know what size we are talking about? My plugin says around 160k raw and 60 gzipped, but I am not sure if that's accurate,

Comment: with this simple requirement i have a way without losing any extra dimensions. I'll leave it in the answer

Comment: i looked through the package you mentioned it's not the actual size you have to include the vue compiler size. according to my calculations vue template compiler is around 47.4kb

Comment: Oh, yes, I knew you were not talking about the plugin. I get 80kB/30kB unzipped.

Answer (score 1):

if you just have simple and uncomplicated components like `v-for`, `v-slot` you don't need a compiler executable:

```js
import { openBlock, createElementBlock, Fragment, createVNode, createElementVNode, toDisplayString, createTextVNode} from 'vue'

/// your code

const html = ref(props.data.text)
const FaqItem = resolveComponent('FaqItem')

const Result = {
    setup() {
      return (_ctx, _cache) => {
        
        const indexFaq = html.value.indexOf("[faq]")
        
        if (indexFaq === -1)
            return toDisplayString(msg)
        
        openBlock()
        return createElementBlock(Fragment, null, [
          createTextVNode(html.value.slice(0, indexFaq), 1),
          createVNode(FaqItem),
          createTextVNode(html.value.slice(indexFaq + 5), 1)
        ], 64 /* STABLE_FRAGMENT */ )
      }
    }
}
```

and

```js
<div class="block prose xl:mt-12">
  <Result />
</div>
```

Here is a method using `low api`s that allows you to solve the problem without increasing the compilation package size and reducing performance as suggested by @MoritzRingler

anyway for normal application this doesn't increase any size, don't worry about the inputs as it is always imported if you use vue component(Fragment, text)

if you don't like `Fragment` you can use `createElementBlock('div',...)`

View [demo](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9VG1v2jAQ/is3fyF0IVmlbR8QINENpklbJ7VoX+oKpeEC7hI7tR3GhPjvOycmUGgrReJ89/jxc29s2bgso3WFrM8GJtWitGDQVuWIS1GUSlvYgsYshFQVZWVxASEsMBMSv5BDSZQ2BFWivMpV+odgGhOLkxwLinjfVCdLd9xHf1+rBZ5Avc+qr8KUefLv1mohl3vQDDcNYgeZVgV0SHGnVThNnr5bLJoQZ1HsHS4vzrjkEoDLVEljoTBLGLqMgs4K81y9A7sSBui7y5Kn+07XwRvoDZoqt4TeOgJo6hJ090cgFltpCcE8tZsQ5mmSrrALw9EB4d7dWw2pkAvckD6iJSnROskrjGrnryzgrBbBGak4JxAZBIfrwyH0Lo9whLRe0EkRA3roRcK2bcFR2HOc9zE4tFFWeR7C3fHjJ31yb/rkTC5SDD6EberdEC674fnl5qLv3UuA19nbsryHTzX94fJ9CJ8/QnwBt7Px1Y/JfHoz/vZzcj2Dixha2K4eEUs/9A3iZhFoBehAWqiUFukEfiT6zhw86Lj2HYwmOhrE3mjmrkbAKbZ1TRaCphKNSZbYEAtJiwbrXkGZ5kPOKFnOCDuIWy0sZM3s94qkjB6NkrS/9dRxHzCc9fdzyFm9CH0yVtaWph/HJkvddjyaSOllTFakK2lFgRGaoveg1V+Dmog5832oOWJyrlH3NFK9Neq3OE+gZ7yO1tWbUjlaV/c3dFRxbn3sefa7/wGzhwY=)

Answer (score 0):

v-html can only handle simple HTML.
I'm assuming your component already exists and that it is used for all FAQs. If there are different FAQs per call you can pass them as props.

So if your component already exists simply import it and include it in your template after your v-html, with a v-if directive which you can set if props.data.text contains "[faq]". You would replace "[faq]" with a blank.

If you must load the component dynamically you will need to use the Vue "Component" with v-bind:is="YourComponent" to included it in your template.