# how can i use dynamic component in Nuxt.js 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt3

I am trying to render dynamic components. it doesn't work.

```js
<component :is="comp" />
```

The variable `comp` is filled with the name of the component in the course of the process (CardComponent).

I don't get any error messages either. Nothing happens.

what should i can do?

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to check if the component has been imported. All components has been imported under `components/globals`, so you do not need to import anything in this component (just name needed). This solution should not create any performance issue, do to tree-shaking.

```js
    <component
      v-if="isComponentExist(componentName)"
      :is="resolveComponent(componentName))"
    />
```

```
    const instance = getCurrentInstance();

    const isComponentExist = (name) => {
        return instance?.appContext.components[name)];
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

refs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73029625/17662593

```
<script setup>
const foo = resolveComponent('foo')
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <component :is="foo" />
  </div>
</template>
```